# select default product color in scandipwa

Tags: magento, magento2, progressive-web-apps, pdp

Working on a scandipwa project, it have configurable product have colr and size option.I need to select a default color on page load.current it comes with no default color selected.
How to select color on product page reload on scandipwa?